# How to accept a dot within email address with Regex?

Tags: regex

I have this regex `[a-z0-9]*@metu\.edu` which checks user input userside, using HTML5. I want to accept a dot (.) within the username, only a single dot. Such as: herp.derp@metu.edu

Comment: You might find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses) post on SO helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use below

```
^[a-z0-9]+[.]?[a-z0-9]+@metu\.edu$
```

**[DEMO](http://www.rubular.com/r/LztvLlVQVf)**

Comment: This doesn't address the requirements given

Comment: You dropped the digits... ilhan wrote: "only alphanumeric with a single dot".

Comment: This will match `herp.@metu.edu` If that's undesirable, use `^[a-z0-9]+(\.[a-z0-9]+)?` - Matches `herp` & `herp.derp` & `herpderp` but not `.herp` or `herp.`

Answer (score 3):

```
[a-z0-9][a-z0-9.]*@metu\.edu\.tr
```

This will require at least one (lower case character or number) and then (lower case character or number or dot), so email addresses cannot begin with or only consist of a single dot. However you should probably reconsider using this regex for email validations, as the acceptable email addresses contain a lot more cases (-, +, _ etc.) (and don't forget size limitations as well)

Comment: You're right, plus it also allows dot at the end of the local part, which is not formally valid according to RFC5322.

Comment: This answered a semi-related question of my own, thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Add a dot to the character range: `[a-z0-9.]*`

To exclude dots at the beginning or end of the name, and only allow a single dot use multiple character classes:

```
[a-z0-9]+\.?[a-z0-9]+@metu\.edu
```

Comment: This is a single character optionally followed by a dot, you are probably missing a "+" after the first character class.

Comment: @Zaki you are right, I added a `+`, and changed the last `*` as well. Tested and is matching `herp.derp@metu.edu` now but not `herpderp.@metu.edu` or `herp.derpity.derp@metu.edu`

Answer (score 1):

In general, e-mail addresses shouldn't be matched with regexes. However, in your specific case, it seems that you have a distinct pattern that you want to match against.

```
[a-z0-9]+(\.[a-z0-9]+)?@metu\.edu
```

Assuming that the single dot is optional, if it's mandatory, use this:

```
[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]+@metu\.edu
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be trying to parse e-mail adresses yourself, using regex, as you WILL fail. Please consider this: http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

What I usually do is accept any string as e-mail. If it's just for user registration or whatever, there is really no need to validate it. It will fail when you send out an email, then you know it's wrong.

Comment: This is for a university. We don't have different kinds of expressions. only alphanumeric with a single dot.